# HTML5 Input Type "Date" is rendering on my second monitor (Chrome 35)

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, google-chrome, datepicker

I am working on a project for an internal Angular/Node application that is targeting Google Chrome. We had a requirement for a Date picker, and the default go-to was AngularUI (Angular wrappers for the jQuery UI components). We had previously avoided jQuery (Angular already has jQLite) and jQuery UI.

It seemed that the HTML5 Date Input element was the perfect solution. Lite, no jQuery, etc. For some reason though, it sometimes opens the calendar dropdown on another monitor.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Is the Date input just not usable yet?

I have an image that shows the behavior. The left monitor is my secondary monitor and the right is my primary (you can see the green background where this monitor starts).

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a Chrome issue that was supposed to be solved in version 20, but it was not. The problem occurs when you have more than one display, the date will always popup on the main display. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123976

Comment: Thanks for that thread Hanlet. I posted there, but it looks like it is a bit old. ;)